# How to get a list of warnings from sphinx compilation

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I am developing a sphinx based collaborative writing tool. Users access the web application (developed in python/Flask) to write a book in sphinx and compile it to pdf.

I have learned that in order to compile a sphinx documentation from within python I should use

```
import sphinx
result = sphinx.build_main(['-c', 'path/to/conf',
                            'path/to/source/', 'path/to/out'])
```

So far so good.

Now my users want the app to show them their syntax mistakes. But the output (`result` in the example above) only gives me the exit code.

So, how do I get a list of warnings from the build process?

Perhaps I am being too ambitious, but since sphinx is a python tool, I was expecting to have a nice pythonic interface with the tool. For example, the output of `sphinx.build_main` could be a very rich object with warnings, line numbers...

On a related note, the argument to the method `sphinx.build_main` looks just like a wrapper to the command line interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sphinx.build_main()` calls `sphinx.cmdline.main()`, which in turn creates a [`sphinx.application.Sphinx`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/extdev/appapi.html#sphinx.application.Sphinx) object. You could create such an object directly (instead of "making system calls within python"). Use something like this:

```
import os
from sphinx.application import Sphinx

# Main arguments 
srcdir = "/path/to/source"
confdir = srcdir
builddir = os.path.join(srcdir, "_build")
doctreedir = os.path.join(builddir, "doctrees")
builder = "html"

# Write warning messages to a file (instead of stderr)
warning = open("/path/to/warnings.txt", "w")

# Create the Sphinx application object
app = Sphinx(srcdir, confdir, builddir, doctreedir, builder, 
             warning=warning)

# Run the build
app.build()
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you used [`sphinx-quickstart`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/invocation.html#invocation-of-sphinx-quickstart) to generate your initial Sphinx documentation set with a [makefile](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/invocation.html#makefile-options), then you can use `make` to build docs, which in turn uses the Sphinx tool [`sphinx-build`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/invocation.html#invocation-of-sphinx-build).  You can [pass the `-w <file>` option to `sphinx-build`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/invocation.html#cmdoption-sphinx-build-w) to write warnings and errors to a file as well as `stderr`.

Note that options passed through the command line override any other options set in the makefile and `conf.py`.

Comment: The `-w` option is very useful, thanks. But it feels very strange to keep making system calls within python to run sphinx, which is a python solution.