# Make sphinx-build raise exceptions so that IDE can catch them?

Tags: python, pycharm, python-sphinx

When trying to fix a Sphinx build error, having my IDE drop into a breakpoint upon catching the exception would be extremely useful. However, it seems `sphinx-build` is catching the exceptions, and then not fully raising them to the IDE. Is there a way to tell `sphinx-build` to raise the exception fully?

More specifically, in my IDE (PyCharm), I have a run configuration to run `sphinx-build`. If I add a breakpoint in the Sphinx `conf.py`, the debugger correctly drops into the breakpoint. With the IDE's exception catching enabled, I expect the IDE to drop into a breakpoint on an exception (as it does with any other Python run). However, it looks like `sphinx-build` is catching the exception, printing its own output error message, and not raising the exception further. It seems to be doing this so that it can output its own message after the error. Since it doesn't raise the exception, the IDE can't catch it. Is there a way to force `sphinx-build` to raise all exceptions fully? I can't seem to find an option in the [regular `sphinx-build` arguments](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-build.html). Or is there another workaround?

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible when you start the sphinx build process directly from python script, like shown [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47657926/7306999).

Answer (score 1):

@Xukrao's answer pointed me in the right direction, but I wanted to give a more detailed answer for future readers.

**Solution**

Use your own Sphinx build script. For example,

```
from pathlib import Path
from sphinx.application import Sphinx

docs_directory = Path('.').absolute()
source_directory = docs_directory
configuration_directory = docs_directory
build_directory = Path(configuration_directory, '_build')
doctree_directory = Path(build_directory, '.doctrees')
builder = 'html'

app = Sphinx(source_directory, configuration_directory, build_directory, doctree_directory, builder)
app.build()
```

In this case, the source code is in the project root directory and the `conf.py` file is in a `docs` directory within the project root. The source code path is being added in the `conf.py`. Here, we create the Sphinx builder app ourselves and pass in the appropriate directories.

**Explanation**

With the version of `sphinx-build` at the time of writing, it is impossible to get the script to raise the exceptions. This is because any call of `sphinx-build` and related scripts end up calling the Sphinx package's `build_main` function. This function does something similar to our custom build script above, but it wraps the entire call in a `try/except` statement that catches all exceptions. The script then manually handles the exceptions, printing our the errors and related information. However, this handling does not raise (and has no option to raise) the exception up farther. So for the current Sphinx version, `sphinx-build` exceptions can never reach the IDE.